# Adding database generated IDs to seed data in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have an Entity Framework Core code-first database and a .Net 5 application. I have seeded some initial values into a table using the `.HasData` method.

Here is the gist of my RailcarEvent entity class:

```
    public class RailcarEvent
    {
        public Guid RailcarEventId { get; set; }
        public string Identifier { get; set; }
    }
```

I created a helper class that contains the IDs for some of these `RailcarEvent`s. The main advantage here is that since these `Guid`s are declared in a static class, I can use `RailcarEventIdentifiers` kind of like an enum.

```
    public static class RailcarEventIdentifiers
    {
        public static readonly Guid ArriveDest = new Guid("49DB8ECD-1D26-46A1-BD39-AF358EDEB17D");
        public static readonly Guid ArriveInTransit = new Guid("8F3D8BE4-E745-406D-B361-1A81B9A5C410");

        public static readonly List<RailcarEvent> All = new()
        {
            new RailcarEvent
            {
                RailcarEventId = ArriveDest,
                Identifier = "Arrive Dest"
            },
            new RailcarEvent
            {
                RailcarEventId = ArriveInTransit,
                Identifier = "Arrive In-Transit"
            }
        };
    }
```

For example, this allows me to compare property `myRailcar.RailcarEventId` to `RailcarEventIdentifiers.ArriveDest` in my code.

I have seeded the `RailcarEvent` table in my DbContext like so:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<RailcarEvent>().HasData(RailcarEventIdentifiers.All);;
        }
```

My application is also able to dynamically add entries to the `RailcarEvent` entity if a new event is detected. For this entity, it happens infrequently enough that I am okay with checking the table once in a while to see what the new events are, then manually add them to the code with the `Guid` from the table.

I want the ability to reference these new application-created `RailcarEvent`s in the same way as the others in my code, but when I add the application-created `RailcarEvent`s to my `RailcarEventIdentifiers.All` list and attempt a migration, I get conflicting key errors saying that the data already exists in the database (and it does). I don't care that it already exists and would just like to ignore this error and continue.

Is there a way to create a migration that will not cause these conflicting key errors?

Is there a better way to track these static IDs? I'd be open to hearing that as well.

Comment: `I am okay with checking the table once in a while to see what the new events are, then manually add them to the code with the Guid from the table`. If you ask me, this indicates a design issue. The fact that you are relying on these values to be hard coded within your source code and also plan to allow end users to enter them and THATS your plan to manage the records is a major design flaw.

Comment: Secondly, IMO the fact that the keys collide is actually another issue. Is the GUID actually the unique key? If so then I don't understand why you would want to ignore the conflicting key errors? If the GUID is not actually a unique key (which might be why you don't care if they collide), then you need to change that within your database/object design to reflect that. Then at the very least the reported error might be resolved.

Comment: Typically, no I wouldn't hard code IDs. This is sort of a unique situation. There are about 12 `RailcarEvent`s in that table right now. As of now, there's only been a need to add a couple more. Doing it this way allowed me to do business logic against `Railcar`s that had these specific `RailcarEvent`s attached to them at the time. To the key-colliding point, since I'm copying these created GUIDs from the database back into the code when necessary to code against, I'm guessing EF assumes that these GUIDs originated code-first and when it finds the same GUIDs in the table, it throws the error.

Comment: Design issues aside, which I would still recommend you address, in order to resolve the error I think there is a bit more info needed. What type of exception are you receiving and where are you receiving it? Are you receiving while attempting to apply migrations, generate migrations, or something else?